# How to use hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs to create directory structure using oozie workflow?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am running my MR jobs using workflow:0.5". My use case to create key based directory structure for output.
This is my configuration file:-

```
`           
        <configuration>
                <!-- These are important. -->
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queue.name}
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
                    <value>com.a.b.c.Amapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>com.a.b.c.Areducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.outputformat.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>${inputDir}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>`
```

In reducer, i want to create formatted directory structure using this code-

```
`public class Areducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text aggregatorRecord = new Text();
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> out;

    public void setup(Context context) {
        out = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
    }

    public void reduce(Text aggregatorRecordKey,
            Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /** 
           some business logic to do aggregation to set aggregatorRecord.
        */
        String plist = "Surname|Forename";
        Text t = new Text(plist);
        out.write(aggregatorRecordKey, aggregatorRecord, generateFileName(t));
    }

    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        out.close();
    }

    private String generateFileName(Text k) {
        String[] kStr = k.toString().split("\\|");

        String sName = kStr[0];
        String fName = kStr[1];

        // example for k = Smith|John
        // output written to /user/hadoop/path/to/output/Smith/John-r-00000
        // (etc)
        return sName + "/" + fName;
    }
```

`

oozie workflow gives this exception

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.<\init>()

**Can someone suggest the correct approach to use MultipleOutputs to create directory structure using oozie workflow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that MultipleOutputs is not an OutputFormat and so you don't set it as the output format for your job.  I usually use a java class to configure and submit my MultipleOutputs jobs, but looking at your code I think what you need to to is set your output format type to TextOutputFormat and leave your references to reducer variable as they are.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It worked. 
Initially, i was stuck with defining <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs</value> but changing this to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output. TextOutputFormat, solved my problem. But i am getting directory file structure in output like this:-
/outputDir/Surname
/outputDir/Surname/Forename-r-00000
/outputDir/_SUCCESS
/outputDir/part-r-00000,
I want to get _SUCCESS inside 'Surname' directory with Forename-r-00000(as it require for flag to initiate other dependent job). So without writing java class, is it not possible to get it?